# Connecting Bluetooth Socket While Device Discovery is On

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using bluetooth socket connection in my andorid app to connect to medical devices in near range.I want to connect the bluetooth socket by clicking on a particuar device on the ListView,while the bluetooth discovery is not finished yet.
I am using the follwoing code to connect the bluetooth socket to connect to a device found in the bluetooth range.

```
BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;

mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
                                .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

                        if (mBluetoothSocket != null) {
                            // Device does not support Bluetooth
                            Log.w("MyDebugMsg", "Bluetooth Socket present");
                            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                            mDialog2 = ProgressDialog.show(HL7MedicalAppActivity.this,
                                    "", "Connecting to device, Please wait...",
                                    true);

                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        mBluetoothSocket.connect();

                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                                        HL7MedicalAppActivity.this);
                                                // Setting Dialog Title
                                                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                                                // Setting Dialog Message
                                                alertDialog
                                                        .setMessage("Connection refused by remote device");
                                                // Setting OK Button
                                                alertDialog
                                                        .setPositiveButton(
                                                                "OK",
                                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                                    public void onClick(
                                                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                            int id) {
                                                                        HL7MedicalAppActivity.this
                                                                                .finish();
                                                                    }
                                                                });

                                                // Showing Alert Message
                                                alertDialog.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

But if I try to connect before device discovery is finished it is showing me follwing Bluetooth Socket Connect error

```
04-09 19:03:32.720: W/MyDebugMsg(5463): Bluetooth Socket present
04-09 19:03:32.730: I/BluetoothAdapterProperties(2879):    
Callback:discoveryStateChangeCallback with state:0
04-09 19:03:32.730: I/BluetoothAdapterProperties(2879):   
Callback:discoveryStateChangeCallback with state:0
04-09 19:03:32.740: V/BluetoothDiscoveryReceiver(2847): Received:   
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED
 04-09 19:03:32.740: D/audio_hw_primary(177): select_devices: out_snd_device(2:     
 speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
 04-09 19:03:32.740: D/ACDB-LOADER(177): ACDB -> send_afe_cal
 04-09 19:03:32.750: W/BluetoothAdapter(5463): getBluetoothService() called with no  
 BluetoothManagerCallback
 04-09 19:03:32.750: D/BTIF_SOCK(2879): service_uuid:     
 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 04-09 19:03:32.750: E/bt-btif(2879): DISCOVERY_COMP_EVT slot id:12, failed to find  
 channle,                                       status:2, scn:-86134667
 04-09 19:03:32.750: W/bt-btif(2879): invalid rfc slot id: 12
04-09 19:03:32.750: D/BluetoothSocket(5463): connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd:         {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[58]}
04-09 19:03:32.750: W/System.err(5463): java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might 
closed or timeout, read ret: -1
04-09 19:03:32.750: W/System.err(5463):     at  
android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:505)
04-09 19:03:32.750: W/System.err(5463):     at   
android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:516)
04-09 19:03:32.750: W/System.err(5463):     at 
 android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:320)
04-09 19:03:32.750: W/System.err(5463):     at        
com.example.hl7medicalapp.HL7MedicalAppActivity$4$1.run(HL7MedicalAppActivity.java:389)
04-09 19:03:32.750: W/System.err(5463):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Can anyone suggest how to connect this BT socket successfully while device discovery is going on?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because you are trying when bluethooth is in discover mode.Discovery mode is very heavy weight process so it blocks.you should try after finishing discovery.you can show toast when user try at time of discovery so that user will wait for that time.